# textarea width (minus scrollbar) using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

Here's a quickie.

Basically, I want the width of a textarea element -- minus the width of the scrollbar if one is present.  I could just use the clientWidth DOM property, but I don't know if this is cross-browser.  I'm sure jQuery has some method (.width() returns the width including scrollbar), but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

clientWidth is cross browser compatible as reported by quirksmode.org (an authority on the matter.)  http://quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html

Comment: Thanks!  That site seems pretty handy; I'll have to bookmark it.